# DOM- XPath - select Nodes by Attribut-Value StartsWith

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I like to select all Nodes, which have any attribut-value starting with a given pattern:

```
<h1 att1="bar" att2="foo">One</h1>
<h2 att1="foo" att2="bar">Two</h2>
<span att1="bar" att2="foo">Three</span>
<h3 att1="other">None</h3>
<div att1="foo" att2="bar">
  <a href="url.com" att1="bar" att2="foo">Four</a>
  <h4 att1="bar" att2="foo">Five</h4>
  <h5 att1="other">Six</h5>
</div>
```

**Search by 'fo' should return h1, h2, span, div, a, h4**

Best XPath i found matches only if the first Attribut of an element starts with the pattern, **so it returns: h2, div**

```
function GetElementsByAttributValueStartsWith(pattern) {
  var result = document.evaluate(
    '//*[starts-with(@*,"' + pattern + '")]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );

  var items = Array.from({length: result.snapshotLength}, (_, i) => result.snapshotItem(i));
  return items;
}
console.log(GetElementsByAttributValueStartsWith("fo")); //h2, div
//expected: h1, h2, span, div, a, h4
```

how can i tune my XPath-Expression?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/36vfqrd4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it (note: I simplified names a bit to avoid typing errors :D):

```
function myFunct(xpath) {
  let result = document.evaluate(
    xpath,
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  )
  return result}
;
let target = myFunct('//*[@*[starts-with(., "fo")]]');
let node = null;
let tagNames = [];
for(let i = 0; i < target.snapshotLength; i++) {
  let node = target.snapshotItem(i);
  tagNames.push(node.localName);
}
console.log(tagNames)
```

Output:

```
["h1", "h2", "span", "div", "a", "h4"]
```